Anomalous behaviour of a DC-DC booster with LT3461A
I am building a circuit based of the CosmicWatch project, however I had to rebuild the circuit as I'd wished it to be integrated with other systems.
However, powering up the circuit (4.5Vin) instead of the expected ±29V I get roughly the same voltage with ±0.1V; I checked the voltages on the pins in case SHDN wasn't activated or something of that type, but I read all pins to be also 4.5V with the only exception being FB pin with 0.7V.
I read the datasheet and it did mention that FB pin should be at around 1.25V, however I am not quite sure what might be the issue.
The load on the DC-DC booster should not exceed 20mA.
I realise the fault is most likely some silly thing I managed to overlook or insufficient power draw, but I am really on a lookout for help. (I am attaching a picture of the circuit)

You didn't attached picture. Check for shorts on output or inductor. Just by looking at schematic on github: you can disconnect SiPM PCB, attach to output constant resistive load (5 - 10 kOhm for example) and check if output voltage is correct. Also, IC itself can be faulty.

Show your setup as well.
